# Is there computer for specify purpose that perform database task?

Tags: databases

Is database server really really exist? i mean the server wasn't made by general purpose computer but that database device have their own hardware and architecture.

We know that good database server means good in shorting data.

So the database server i mean have hardware that only found inside it which general purpose computer doesn't have it.

So maybe the part hardware theres shorter directly with using logic gates and binary.

I feel every electricity through passing a logic gates have propagation delay. So thats mean less logic gates more faster.

So im not talking about software but a hardware architecture, yes it still need software and probably special OS too for it. It database only perform retrieve and saving data. If data found after shorting process, then it transfer data to general purpose computer.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking.  What do you mean by "shorting data"?  Some advice: A database server that is built using a general-purpose computer is still a database server, so I suggest you describe it differently.  I suspect you are asking whether there is a custom hardware implementation of a hardware server.  This raises the question of what it takes to qualify as a custom hardware implementation; how unusual does the hardware need to be, for you to be satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

Tandem's [NonStop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NonStop_(server_computers)) system used custom hardware to ensure reliability, and was used for transaction processing, i.e., for highly reliable databases.